# Is it better to insert Bootstrap directory in the 'header.php' or 'function.php' file?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

After having spent time working on many WordPress Theme templates, I have decided to have a go at creating a theme from scratch.

I have just uploaded the Bootstrap features onto my server and I am wondering whether it is best to call the Bootstrap.css files within the head tags in the 'header.php' file or whether through the use of the 'function.php' file.

According to the Bootstrap Bay, you simply insert the lines as follows:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
</head>
```

Alternatively, what I have done is inserted the following code into my 'functions.php' file:

```
function theme_name_script_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/theme-name.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/theme-name.js', array(), '1.0', true);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_script_enqueue' );
```

I then placed the following code, between the head and body tags in the 'header.php' file as follows:

```
<?php 

        if( is_home() ):
            $theme_name_classes = array( 'theme-name-class', 'my-class' );
        else:
            $theme_name_classes = array( 'no-theme-name-class' );
        endif;  

    ?>
```

I have tested the files and the CSS is being picked up ok, so far.  That said, does anyone know of any reasons that my alternative way should be avoided?  For example, is it bad practice, or would it affect website performance etc?

Thanks.

Craig

Comment: Enqueue is best. Generally what you've done is good practice

Comment: Thank you @JamesJones.  I thought as much but as a relative newbie to php, I wanted to double check as many of the 'default installation' guides, simply advised to install within the <head> tags, in the 'headper.php' file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General rule of thumb is Stylesheet's in the header and javascript's in the footer.  Mainly for site speed and SEO although your users will likely not notice the difference as far as site speed goes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Brandon Orndorff.  Are you saying that your suggestion would be a better approach than what I have posted?  If so, my question would be that wouldn't my website be restricted to the same stylesheet for every page or are you saying that I could place 'if functions' within the <head> tags, to call the relevant CSS files, depending in the page?

Comment: Your approach is perfect I would just move the if statement within the <head> to insure it follows the suggestions by Google.

Comment: 'Move CSS to head' seeks to reduce the number of times the browser must re-flow the document by ensuring that the CSS styles are all parsed in the head, before any body elements are introduced.

This is based on the best practice for optimizing browser rendering...  https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-css-to-head

Comment: Thank you for your advice and follow up suggestion.  I have gone with what you have said and placed the 'if statement' within the <head> tags.  I see no issues as of yet. :-) Thanks, once again.